# Custom Input Validation for ASP.Net MVC4 Web Api Url Parameter Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Does anyone know if it's possible (or sensible) to do this kind of attribute annotated validation without creating a model class, so just binding url parameters like this?

```
[HttpGet]
public Portfolio Name([MyCustomValidator, FromUri]string path) {}
```

And if so, what's the best approach? Ideally, I'd just like to mark them with validation attributes and have the existing model binder and value providers do what they normally do but throw out validation errors.

The kind of thing I'd like to do with MyCustomeValidator is check for specific characters or string sequences not picked up by the existing input validators and throw them out. For example;

```
path = "/foor/bar" /* is valid */
path = "$.^\n/bar" /* is illegal */
```

Even more specifically, (in case anyone points me towards XssEncoder or UrlRewrite), I'm looking to ensure that the characters in path are part of the Base64 charset.